# Abstract structural types implementation

Tags: scala, generics

I am trying to understand abstract structural types. Suppose I have a trait

```
trait Test {

  type Foo = String => Unit

  def printFoo(s : Foo) = {
    println(s)
  }
}
```

and a simple function

```
val foo : String => Unit = (s : String) => println(s)
```

How will I implement this function in a class? When I try

```
  val s = new Test {
    override type Foo = String => Unit
  }
```

and try to implement

```
s.printFoo(foo("Test"))
```

It does not work.

Comment: What do you mean "it doesn't work"? What do you expect? What happens?

Comment: You should pass `foo` not `foo("Test")` for the types to match.

Comment: @erip - I want to pass a String and use foo in printFoo.

Comment: @Lukasz - that gives me a function. How will I then use it with s string "Test"

Comment: @Srinivas Just pass the string to that function?

Comment: @Duelist - it takes a foo, so it has to be a type of String => Unit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your method `printFoo` gets a lambda, you are printing the function object. 
One way to solve your issue is by providing multiple parameter lists:

```
trait Test {

  type Foo = String => Unit

  def printFoo(f: Foo)(s: String) = {
    f(s)
  }
}

val foo : String => Unit = (s : String) => println(s)

val s = new Test {
  override type Foo = String => Unit
}

s.printFoo(foo)("something")

// or reuse it:
val doFoo: String => Unit = s.printFoo(foo)
doFoo("something A...")
doFoo("something B...")
```

Comment: Yes you are right, I somehow thought that the function (foo) will be executed when called and I will see the output.